# Simple, library-free, Javascript method for inserting a file into Google Drive

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using a web scripting service that generates files and can POST them to a URI. If I don't have or provide one, they are stored on an ftp server. What I want to do is upload these files to my Google Drive, and, eventually, other users' Drives as well.
Because I'm using a 'private' host, and 'pure' javascript--no browser-- I can't add any framework or library. I have to do everything by hand.

I've been through all the documentation, read many posts here, found some really good information, and have lost some hair.

Here's where the project is at the moment:
I'm using oauth2, web server flow. 
I can request access, and get an auth code, like so:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
    response_type=code
   &scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
   &redirect_uri=http://myserver.com/
   &access_type=offline
   &state=testing
   &client_id={CLIENT_ID].apps.googleusercontent.com
```

This gets me an auth code. So far, so good.

Then, I take that code and do:

```
POST /o/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host:  https://accounts.google.com
client_id=yada_yada
&client_secret=more_yada
&redirect_uri=http://myserver.com/
&code=[the code I just got]
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Now, this step fails if I use XMLHttpRequest; I get an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin' violation. So, I slapped together an HTML page with a form and posted **that**. I get back a JSON object containing an access_token and a refresh_token. Yay.

```
{
  'access_token'  : [Access Yada-Yada],
  'expires_in'    : 3600,
  'token_type'    : 'Bearer',
  'refresh_token' : '[Refresh Yada-Yada]
}
```

Now, I can get my script to work for one hour. Yippee.

Now, after all that, how do I use the refresh_token to get a new access_token. I have tried everything. XMLHttpRequests give me the same cross-domain violation, and doing an HTML form gets me an 'invalid_request' response! I tried using curl, never having touched it before, and that did **not** go well.

Please help.

**Edit**

The format for the refresh request goes like this:

```
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST',"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth/token?" +
    "client_id=[CLIENT_ID]"+
   "&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]"+
   "&refresh_token=[REFRESH_TOKEN]"+
   "&grant_type=refresh_token",
  true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send();
```

I copied the url parameters directly from the OAuth Playground, which I had given my project keys. I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin violation when I do this.

If I wrap it in a form, like so:

```
<form method="GET" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token">
<div>REFRESH TOKEN:</div>
  <input type="text" name="refresh_token" value="[REFRESH_TOKEN]">
<br><div>CLIENT ID:</div>
  <input type="text" name="client_id"     value="[CLIENT_ID]">
<br><div>CLIENT SECRET:</div>
  <input type="text" name="client_secret" value="[CLIENT_SECRET">
<br><div>GRANT TYPE:</div>
  <input type="text" name="grant_type"    value="refresh_token">
</form>
```

I can get a new access token. But, I can't get the same thing to work in JS using XMLHttpRequest. I keep getting XD errors.

I just need a way to post a refresh request to google from javascript without using any libraries.

Comment: Check out this link (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). You can follow the whole process and examine the syntax of each request.

Comment: What does your XMLHttpRequest look like?  Have you checked the SDK samples, e.g. for Python [DrEdit > client.py > OAuth2Credentials._generate_refresh_request_body etc.](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/blob/master/python/lib/oauth2client/client.py#L533)

Comment: The OAuth Playground works just fine, even when I give it my own project credentials. I just can't get a new token with a refresh token by myself. The python examples use generally the same setup that I have, but when I duplicate that in my code, I either get cross domain violations or invalid request responses.

Comment: If you only want to upload to your own drive. You can generate a refresh token in the oauth playground and then simply store that somewhere in your server. Of course, make sure you've set your own client id etc first. When it comes to having multiple users grant access, you'll need to implement the auth flow and redirects as described in the docs.

Comment: Yes, @pinoyyid, I can use my own host to do the auth for each user and send the refresh tokens to my script on the service I'm using. But how do I call /o/oauth/token?refresh_token=... from my script without getting a cross-domain violation?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to convert a refresh token to an access token from a browser. That breaks the whole OAuth security model since it places the ultra secret refresh token on an unsecure client. refresh_token is exclusively for server flows.

Comment: I'm not, at least that's not the ultimate goal. I have a service on a secure host that runs server-side JS. That is where the auth/access/refresh needs to happen. There is no browser, and no libs available. If I could, I would just use the gapi. I can get that to work just fine on my own site, but I can't load anything on the other host.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver flow is not adequate for an application that only has client-side logic. I recommend you use the G+ Sign-In widget (which can be customized for any scope, including Drive and actually works for all Google users whether or not they happen to have a Google+ account, including all Google Apps users). https://developers.google.com/+/

If you'd rather do it all yourself, you can read on how the client-side flow works: Essentially you ask for 'response_type=token' and parse the access_token from the fragment. There's no refresh_token for access_token exchange step. You can periodically refresh the token in the background using an invisible iframe by just repeating the initial authorization request. make sure you add display=none to requests you make in invisible iframe. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent for more information.

Comment: No html, no browser, no ui (not web based, at least). Just server-side JS. I can do XMLHttpRequests, that's about it. I can get the callback from the authorization, and store the token to use for an hour, but this requires constantly having to reauthorize the app. I just can't get the refresh_token to refresh!

Comment: I believe you could use XMLHttpRequest to request another token after one hour using display=none&response_type=token. That'll not require re-authorization.

Comment: I can use an xhr to get data from the Drive API, but when I go to get a new token I get a domain violation.

Comment: I can't even use XMLHttpRequest. The host 'removed it' from JS due to 'security risks.' Case closed.